# MyBatis 2nd Level Cache. How can I use MyBatis 2nd level cache for storing my java objects?

Tags: ehcache, mybatis, ibatis, spring-mybatis

Can I use myBatise 2nd level cache to store java objects...
I am building a spring project. In which I am using mybatis.

I found that my batis uses ehcace for 2nd level cache.
Can I use the my batis ehcache to store my java objects that are not fetched from db or else do i have to mantain my own cache implementation only? I know I can implement my own ehcache implementation but using an already existing cache will be better..

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Ehcache can be used to cache anything you want. You seem to use Spring so for instance, Spring has a nice caching layer that can be backed by Ehcache. You have an example [here](https://github.com/ehcache/ehcache3-samples/tree/master/fullstack) using spring-boot and hibernate. But the principle is the same for mybatis.